# Photoshop CS6 crashes every time clicking text button

Tags: 14.10, crash, text, button, photoshop

Every time I click text button on photoshop it just crashes, is there a solution for this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4rhV.png

Thanks

Update: I have microsoft fonts installed, is it possible that adobe font is required?

Comment: Running with Wine ??

Comment: yup, wine 1.7 and tried 1.6; both failed.

Comment: Have you looked on WineHQ? I also know that PlayOnLinux has a photoshop install helper to work out some bugs.

Comment: Big softwares like Photoshop which require many components and plugins do not work well with wine. Make sure that you have installed all necessary frameworks.

Comment: @robobenklein does it work perfectly well with PlayOnLinux?

Comment: @RohithMadhavan what additional framework does it require when everything except the text addition works perfectly well.

Comment: Try installing Adobe Type Manager.

Comment: It provides the atmlib.dll file which has solved the issue for users facing a similar problem.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan no use still doesn't work. installed the type manager lite edition. Doesn't change anything the screen still goes black.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan trying this, however would have to wait till I get home: http://geebzor.com/tech/linux/complete-guide-to-running-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-13-10/

Comment: `winetricks atmlib` might solve the problem.

Comment: Said already installed after applying all changes restarted and it everything works perfectly. Have no clue which one actually was the solution :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was suffering this problem. I just downloaded atmlib.dll and pasted it `drive_c/windows/system32` as told in [here](http://ohbuntu.blogspot.com.tr/2009/12/run-photoshop-cs4-wine-ubuntu-karmic.html).

The author of article does not really know how much time he saved. I now run Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 16.04 and works like a charm.

I hope anyone finds this solution by googling.

Answer (score 1):

in terminal, use:

```
winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko
```